# WSO2 How to persist changes in registry files after restart

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have deployed some applications into my WSO2 ESB but I have found an unexpected behaviour. I have usually several configuration xmls which must be modified after deployment (endpoints are the typical scenario). What I have found is that if the system is restarted by any reason, all carbons files are deployed again, and therefore changes made are lost since all files are replaced during the deployment process.

The only way that occurs to me to avoid this is to remove configuration files from carbon deployment files, and handle them as simple files you upload to the registry, but this behaviour makes the set up/development process a longer and difficult one.

How can I prevent from modifying files replacement?

Comment: As I understood in here you are saving an endpoint config xml in the registry and the modifications does not get persisted when a server restart , right? But the actual behavior is once you saved a change either in registry or file system those changes get persisted, and even if the server restarts the changes would not get reverted. What is the ESB version you are using ? How do you create and deploy endpoints or other configurations ? is it using WSO2 dev studio ? or using management console ?

Comment: You are right. Now, I change the endpoint, restart the system, and the endpoint is the one set in the carbon archive. I use esb 4.5.1. I generate my own carbon files, based on the carbon generated by eclipse, because I have to develope a lot of services and eclipse is quite unuseful for this.